# Angular2 attribute directive Hostbinding to host attribute

Tags: angular

I have a "bootstrapModal" attribute directive that adds bootstrap attributes to the host element:

```
data-placement="top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DefaultModalWindow"
```

Is it possible to `HostBinding` to an attribute like this?

```
<htmltag ... bootstrapModal placement="left">
```

And in the directive have something like that:

```
 @HostBinding('attributes.data-placement') // <== this don't work
 @Input() placement:string='top';
```

So the result should be:

```
<htmltag ... data-placement="left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DefaultModalWindow">
```

Comment: do you want to bind it dynamically or statically?

Comment: That should work fine if but hard to tell what you are actually trying to accomplish whithout seeing more code.

Comment: @micronyks better dynamically.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should work:

```
@HostBinding('attr.data-placement')
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K196Ed43Np9YnU7l5uqQ?p=preview)**

See also

- https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding

Comment: It works. Where can I find documentation about these properties?  attr? and others

Comment: http://angular.io There aren't many. `class`, `attr`, `style`, `style.xxx.px`, `style.xxx.%` (and probably all other valid units). Did I miss some?