# How to create an Angular directive to disable input fields

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a directive to be applied to inputs and buttons, that will disable the element based on a condition that I get from a service.

I have already reviewed, and tried the following:

- [Button @Directive to bind disable attribute via @Input in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798383/button-directive-to-bind-disable-attribute-via-input-in-angular)
- [Angular2 attribute directive Hostbinding to host attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285955/angular2-attribute-directive-hostbinding-to-host-attribute)
- I have tried using just `disabled` for the HostBinding, but I get `Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.`
- I have tried using `attr.disabled`, but then I get `` Attempted to set attribute `disabled` on a container node. Host bindings are not valid on ng-container or ng-template. ``
- I am sure that I am not trying to bind to ng-container or ng-template, I am binding directly to a button or input as in the example below
- I am able to bind directly to disabled using `[disabled]="condition"`, but that is not what I want here

Here is what I currently have for the directive:

```
export class InputPermissionsDirective {
  @Input() set appCanModify(name:string) {
    this.canModify(name);
  }
  @HostBinding('disabled') disabled:boolean = false;

  constructor(private permissionsService:PermissionsService) { }

  private canModify(name:string) {
    const routePermissions = this.permissionsService.getPermissionsByRoute(window.location.pathname);

    if(!routePermissions) this.disabled = true;
    else {
      const componentPermissions = this.permissionsService.getPermissionsByComponentName(routePermissions, name)

      if(componentPermissions && componentPermissions.CanModify) this.disabled = false;
      else this.disabled = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Here, the permissions service queries for the permission levels associated with the input name (FooBar in the below example). From there, the disabled attribute should be set according to the element's permission field CanModify.

And here is an example of me using this directive:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="foo" *appCanModify="'FooBar'">
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, and I can provide additional info as needed. Thanks!

Comment: You ought to be able to bind directly to the [disabled] property on buttons. Are you sure you've imported CommonModule, within the module which the button is being used?

Comment: Yes, CommonModule is imported through out my application through a shared module export. I can still bind to disabled using brackets as you mentioned on input fields and buttons just fine, but I need to do the disabling through a directive for this use case.

Comment: Try using your directive as an ordinary directive, instead of a structural directive, since you aren't injecting any ViewContainerRef, nor TemplateRef. So `directiveName` rather than `*directiveName`

Comment: Ah, I will give that a try. Was going through tutorials originally that included the asterisk, was unaware of the difference. I will give that a try and read up on the differences, thanks!

Comment: @MikkelChristensen that worked! Thanks so much for your help. If you want to provide that comment as an official post I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue was that I was trying to use this directive as a structural directive by using the asterisk. Instead, I needed to use it as `appCanModify`

Thanks to @MikkelChristensen for the solution